# Best way to manage log file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know what is the best way to manage log file in node.js. I my case, my application read all files in a directory (each file can have more than 1000 lines) and then send request for each line of each file. Now I would like to save all requests results in my log file.

I am hesitating between write a result after each request as below:

```
fs.readdir(dir, function (err, filenames) {
    filenames.forEach(async function (filename) {
           let data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
           let result = await query.send(data);
           log(result);
    });
});
```

or save all results in an array and then write it in the log file after the process:

```
let array = []; let counter = 0;
fs.readdir(dir, async function (err, filenames) {
    for(filename of filenames) {
        let data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
        let result = await query.send(data)
        array.push(result);
        counter++;
        if(counter === filenames.length) {
             // loop array and log all results
        }
    }
});
```

What is the best solution for better performance ?

Any others suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use `readFileSync` if you want performance. What is `log()` ? Also why not just measure the rime both codes take?

Comment: @JonasWilms why not readFileSync ? This application doesn't have any other job. It only read files and send request. Does it matter ? log() is the function which write data into the log file

Comment: yes it does matter, as your server got multiple cores, if you use `readFile` it can use multiple cores to read the files, with `readFileSync` the JS engine becomes a bottleneck.

Comment: Have you considered using `morgan` to handle logs on your app?